# No p gain specified for pid

Tags: ros, pid, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have made custom urdf for 6 DOF robot, when I run it it shows this error
[image: image description]

I have added ros control to this this is the YAML file

robot:
#list of controllers
joint_state_controller:
type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
publish_rate: 50

```
arm_controller:
  type: "position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"
  joints:
    - base_link_link_1
    - link_1_link_2
    - link_2_link_3
    - link_3_link_4
    - link_4_link_5
    - link_5_link_6
  gains:
    base_link_link_1: {p: 100, i: 0.01, d: 1}
    link_1_link_2:    {p: 100, i: 0.01, d: 1}
    link_2_link_3:    {p: 100, i: 0.01, d: 1}
    link_3_link_4:    {p: 100, i: 0.01, d: 1}
    link_4_link_5:    {p: 100, i: 0.01, d: 1}
    link_5_link_6:    {p: 100, i: 0.01, d: 1}

  constraints:
    goal_time: 10.0                  # Override default

  state_publish_rate:  50            # Override default
  action_monitor_rate: 30            # Override default
  stop_trajectory_duration: 0        # Override default

gripper_controller:
  type: "effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"
  joints:
    - gripper_right_joint
    - gripper_left_joint
  gains:
    gripper_right_joint: {p: 100, i: 1, d: 10, i_clamp: 1.0}
    gripper_left_joint:  {p: 100, i: 1, d: 10, i_clamp: 1.0}
  constraints:
    goal_time: 3.0
    gripper_right_joint:
      goal: 0.02
    gripper_left_joint:
      goal: 0.02
```

i am used ros noetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394253/no-p-gain-specified-for-pid/) by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2022-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error message is coming from `gazebo_ros_control`, not the standard `ros_control` node (which is what the yaml file you provided is for.) Notice the param path name the message complains about contains "gazebo_ros_control", not "arm_controller".  See #q293830 for an example of how to specify the values in a yaml file.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-13**:
Agree with Mike.

**Comment by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on 2022-01-14**:
thanks for that